# Получить путь к файлу изображения на SD карте устройства

Tags: android

Подключил  [processing к android studio](http://android.processing.org/index.html), теперь хотелось бы обрабатывать фото не только, те которые находятся внутри приложения (папка assets), но и ,к примеру, 
 из sd карты: нажать кнопку-галерея-загрузить. В самому  processing имеется метод [loadImage(image)](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некошерно это самому писать, принято использовать внешний `Intent`, самый популярный это [aFileChooser](https://github.com/ivanovpv/aFileChooser) - хоть и старый, но еще вполне рабочий, подключаете его как внешнюю либу и пишете что-то типа:

```
final Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
target.setType("image/*");
target.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);    
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Выбрать файл");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

потом ловите `onActivityResult` с ответным файлом.

Надо только озаботиться:

1. Пермишенами на SD карту (до 6.0 в манифесте, после уже рантайм)
2. Также для новых API надо еще обработать `GrantUriPermission` - [фтыкать сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275898/securityexception-with-granturipermission-when-sharing-a-file-with-fileprovider)